# How to make json object for this type in c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, highcharts

I am working on highcharts and sending data in ajax from c#. it was working fine now i am stuck with some different type of chart data here

previously when i have to send data to chart i simply create properties of series,categories etc

```
public class SeriesQuarter2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Data2> data { get; set; }
}
```

and fill the list of this property and serialize it using javascriptserializer
and store this json string and return to ajax success where i parse using JSON.parse,

so the chart series which i want to make looks like this

```
series: [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [-49.9, 71.5]
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, -78.8]
    }
]
```

Now this is fine, but now i have to send object for this type of series

```
series: [
    {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [-49.9, 71.5]
    },
    {
        type: 'column',
         name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, -78.8]
    },
    {
        type: 'scatter',
        showInLegend: false,
        data: [
            {
                name:'Mydata',
                y: 200,
                mydata : 4,
                color:'red',
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
                }
            }, 
            {
                name:'Mydata2',
                y: 200,
                mydata : -4,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
                }   
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How will i make this type of object which has different properties?

Comment: Make a different type with different properties?

Comment: @Reniuz in series there is a property of data changes , first it has list of numbers then it has different properties name,y,mydata etc

Comment: Start from the beginning...in json series has a list of...some different data. But! that different data has similar fields: name and data. So you can create some kind of base class with field name and generic type data field. Or you can simply find json->c# class converter tool and see what it generates.

Comment: what i get from online is only 4 properties with name,type,showinlegend(bool) and list<object> data . will this work? @Reniuz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here's an idea how it could look like:

```
class RootObject
{
    public List<SeriesItem> series { get; set; } = new List<SeriesItem>();
}

class SeriesItem
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool? showInLegend  { get; set; }
    public List<object> data  { get; set; } = new List<object>();
}

class OtherData
{
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int mydata { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public Marker marker { get; set; }
}

class Marker
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var item1 = new SeriesItem();
item1.type = "column";
item1.name = "Tokyo";
item1.data = new List<object>();
item1.data.AddRange(numbersData);
item1.data.Add(-49.9);
item1.data.Add(71.5);

var otherData1 = new OtherData();
otherData1.name = "MyData";
//...fill other fields

var item2 = new SeriesItem();
item2.type = "scatter";
item2.data.Add(otherData1);

var jsonObject = new RootObject();
jsonObject.series.Add(item1);
jsonObject.series.Add(item2);

//convert jsonObject to json
```

Comment: No problem. Note that I haven't tested this.

Comment: i have tested it

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use any third party serializer like [Newtonsoft json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)  easy,simple,free...

Comment: OP wants to create classes from json. Can this framework do that?

Comment: I assume you will do the class creation once, so you can use online converters. [For example] (https://jsonutils.com/)